# List step by step instructions to turn a properly colored pie of j sectors into a properly colored pie of j+1 sectors

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

A circular disk is cut into n distinct sectors, each shaped like a piece of pie and all meeting at
the center point of the disk. Each sector is to be painted red, green, yellow, or blue in such a way
that no two adjacent sectors are painted the same color. Let Sn be the number of ways to paint
the disk using these four colors.

Consider a pie cut into j sectors with Sj different ways to color it. If you take one of the sectors,
w and subdivide it into two sectors w1 and w2, then wedge new sector, x between them, we now
have a pie of
j - (original sector w) + (3 new sectors w1, w2 and x) = j+2 sectors.
To create a proper coloring of this new pie, let w1 and w2 be colored the same color that w was.
Sector x can now be colored any of the three remaining colors. Therefore there are 3Sj legal
colorings for this new pie with j+2 sectors.

b) 4 pts. List step by step instructions to turn a properly colored pie of j sectors into a properly
colored pie of j+1 sectors (similar to the problem just demonstrated above). How many different
ways could you color that pie? You must use Sj in your expression.

This is what I got, If we divide any sector, let say sector w into two halves w1 and w2 making it a pie of j+1 sector. Let say we keep the color of w1 same as color of w, then w2 has two possible color choices. Does that make 2Sj legal colorings for this new pie?

Also, I thought if we divide a sector(let's say w) in two halves(Let's say w1 and w2) and color the first half(w1) same as the orignial sector (w), w2 has 2 color choice, but sector next to has now one more color choice. I am very confused.

Comment: The argument in the second paragraph is incorrect: it fails to account for all legal colorings of a pie with $j+2$ sectors. For example, it is legal to color the sectors of a $6$-pieces pie in the order RGYRGY. No sector has neighbors that are of identical colors, so this coloring cannot arise from any legal coloring of a $4$-piece pie by splitting one piece in the manner described.

Comment: I think these are two separate problems. Creating a 5-slice pie from a 4-slice pie is different than counting all possible 5-slice pies. I don't think you need recursion to compute the number of ways to color an n-slice pie, even though b) sort of suggests you do.

Comment: The paragraph 2 is subquestion of paragraph 1. If we divide any sector, let say sector w into two halves w1 and w2 making it a pie of j+1 sector. Let say we keep the color of w1 same as color of w, then w2 has two possible color choices. Does that make 2Sj legal colorings for this new pie?